# sharepoint list validation with multiple operators

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list with two numeric fields Sunday and Monday and a currency field rate per job.
I want to validate the list, so that the rate per job is greater than zero.
I also want to check that either Sunday or Monday is greater than zero.
How do I do this using the AND and OR operators?  This is what I tried.

```
=OR(=AND([RatePerJob]>0,[RatePerJob]<50),([Sun]>0 , [Mon]>0))
```

I'm using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below :

```
=AND(AND([RatePerJob]>0,[RatePerJob]<50),OR([Sun]>0 , [Mon]>0))
```

Comment: Glad that my answer worked for you. You could accept it as answer :)

Comment: I thought I had done that by clicking the Up Arrow.  What else should I do?

Comment: I've just pressed the tick.